# Lexical Or Preprocessor Issue saying file not found

Tags: objective-c, osx-yosemite

When trying to build my project I get the error

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue CoreFoundation/CFAvailability.h
```

I tried to remove the CoreFoundation framework and reinstalled it, but that didn't resolve the error.

Following Paul R's request, I confirmed that I can find the file at `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Headers/CFAvaila‌​bility.h`, and that my `SDKROOT` is set to "Latest OS X".  Still the compiler seems unable to find it.

What do I need to configure differently to resolve this error?

Comment: Do you have the CoreFoundation framework in your project ? If not then you need to add it.

Comment: I have Added it but still the same issue. The Issue is in NSObjCRuntime.h file saying CoreFoundation/CFAvailability.h file not found

Comment: Can you see that header file in the CoreFoundation framework ? It should be at `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Headers/CFAvailability.h` if you're using the platform SDK or `.../CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Headers/CFAvailability.h` if you're using a different SDK.

Comment: I checked with the path that you have specified. It is at the right location. I am using MacOsx Platform

Comment: OK - and what SDK have you selected in the project settings ? (The setting is `SDKROOT` and it should be "Latest OS X").

Comment: ya it is latest OS X only I selected Paul R

Comment: You probably have something messed up in your project but it's hard to say what without seeing it. Try looking at the build commands for clues.